# Using Fay in a cabal sandbox

Tags: haskell, cabal, fay

I've just started using both cabal sandboxes and Fay. However, Fay seems unable to find the packages automatically, presumably as they are not in the 'global' cabal package database. I tried unsuccessfully to follow the advice on [this wiki page](https://github.com/faylang/fay/wiki/Package-management-with-Cabal), which to me looked like:

```
./cabal-sandbox/bin/fay.exe --base-path .cabal-sandbox/i386-windows-ghc-7.6.3/fay-base-0.19/src/ Frontend.hs
```

But Fay still complains it `cannot find package fay-base`. Is there something I can do about this, or must I install Fay outside the sandbox?

Comment: Just yesterday I found myself in the same situation :) https://github.com/faylang/fay/wiki/Installing-and-running states that you just have to set `HASKELL_PACKAGE_SANDBOX` to your `packages.conf` but I haven't gotten that to work with cabals sandboxing ...

Comment: I swear I didn't even see the section of the wiki page that mentions sandboxes :P.

Comment: Yep ... I had to search for it too ... and it took a while :)

Comment: I added a note that this page contains sandbox instructions as well, hopefully people will be able to find it easier now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to supply the base path, but you need to point it to the correct package config by passing `--package-conf` or setting the `HASKELL_PACKAGE_SANDBOX` environment variable.

For instance:

```
./.cabal-sandbox/bin/fay --package-conf=.cabal-sandbox/x86_64-osx-ghc-7.6.3-packages.conf.d examples/alert.hs
```

or

```
HASKELL_PACKAGE_SANDBOX=./.cabal-sandbox/x86_64-osx-ghc-7.6.3-packages.conf.d ./.cabal-sandbox/bin/fay examples/alert.hs
```

More information is available at https://github.com/faylang/fay/wiki/Installing-and-running#wiki-sandboxes (I just edited it to make it a bit clearer, and I'll add a link from the other wiki page)

Comment: Thanks heaps! I don't think I found that wiki page in my search :P. I got it working with the `--package-conf` option.

Comment: @AdamBergmark could you please confirm that this actually works with the `HASKELL_PACKAGE_CONFIG` envvar? I am sure that I set that to the `.conf.d` directory and still got the `cannot find package` error.

Comment: Oh sorry that was a typo, it's supposed to be `HASKELL_PACKAGE_SANDBOX`. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Eh yep ... I overread your typo :) ... could you confirm that this actually works for cabals buildin sandboxes?

Comment: It does, I ran that command before adding it to the answer, what error are you getting?